# execvp() inside a pipeline causing whole program to die

Tags: c, pipeline

I'm currently writing a shell in C, and I'm having trouble with my pipeline.

I call the entire function process() line by line, with a parsed tree of commands as the input. process() works perfectly fine on simple commands and redirections so far, so I know that's not the problem.

In the below, my cmdList is an already-parsed I've structured my pipeline such that the child pipes its stdout into the stdin of the parent function. The child represents the left tree of cmdList, while the parent represents the right side. Here's what it looks like when I try to recursively call process():

```
        else if (cmdList->type==PIPE)
        {
            int pipefd[2];
            pid_t fork_result;
            pipe(pipefd);
            fork_result=fork();
            if (fork_result < 0) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure2\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }
            if (fork_result==0) {
                int jo3 = close(pipefd[0]);
                int jo1 = dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                process(cmdList->left);
                exit(EXIT_failure);
            }
            else
            {
                close(pipefd[1]);
                int status;
                wait(&status);
                dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                process(cmdList->right);             //dies here
                fprintf(stderr,"FAIL\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }   
        }
```

This causes my entire program to die, including the main function that calls process(). If I replace my recurisve process() calls with

```
execvp(cmdList->left->argv[0],cmdList->left->argv);
execvp(cmdList->right->argv[0],cmdList->right->argv);
```

then my program runs forever.

Things I've already tried:

1. All dup2's and wait's return as expected, without error.
2. Using a debugger, the program always gets to the execvp's with everything doing fine.
3. As stated, the rest of process() works perfectly on everything not having to do with the pipeline.

I'm not really sure what's going wrong with this. Is there anything that stands out?

Comment: You should never call `fork` and then call `exit` from both processes. That causes any exit handlers in the original process to run twice.

Comment: You've not shown `process()` and yet the trouble occurs in `process()`.  How do you expect us to debug what we can't see? Also note that waiting for one process in a pipeline to die before running the other is a recipe for hang-ups. If the first process writes so much data to the pipe that it blocks, it won't exit until the other process reads some of the data, but the other process won't get a chance to read any of the data until the first dies, which is a deadlock. Review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).